# document expired on browser back

Tags: visualforce

I am displaying records in page block and using the outputLink to redirect to another page passing the id of the record:

`<apex:outputLink value="InnovationDetail?id={!result.innovation.innovationId}">{!result.innovation.title}</apex:outputLink>`

The page redirects fine to the new page, but when I click on the browser back button I get a "document expired" error.  The url address is absolutely correct and if I refresh the page, the page displays fine.

I'm not sure why the page is coming up document expired if the URL is correct?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualforce pages that use apex:form use a form-based view state. This form automatically expires when the form is submitted. This prevents replay situations from occurring (e.g. saving a record a second time or making duplicates, charging a credit card again, etc). Either use AJAX-style navigation (onhashchange, etc), or consider opening your links in a new window/tab. Any action that causes a form submit to occur makes the prior state expire. I'd go so far as to recommend you avoid using apex:form for any type of page that doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the apex:Page attribute of cache = True. The browser will cache your page.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm